# Interpolation parameter in Pug

Tags: html, pug, mixins

I'm using pug mixins.

```
mixin p(content)
  div.text
    p= content

+p("Hello, #[strong world]")
```

But tag interpolation `#[strong ...]` don't work.

Please, tell me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use !{variable}

```
mixin p(content)
  div.text
    p !{content}
```

and native tags

```
+p("Hello, <strong>world</strong>")
```